# Firestore not adding docs to the sub-collection after deleting docs from the sub-collection

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In Firestore, after deleting all the docs in a sub-collection, and then adding them back again, it doesn't add the docs.

It's a strange behaviour, and sometimes the item flashes red in the sub-collection and disappears again. But when I reload the app it will add them in. Anyone know if I'm doing this wrong?

Trying to manage some items in a cart.

Would it just be better to do a query on a collection for any docs containing the uid instead of trying to manager a sub-collection?

Deleting:

```
 _db.collection('carts').doc(uid).collection('items').snapshots().forEach((element) {
    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot in element.docs) {
      snapshot.reference.delete();
    }
  });
```

Adding again:

```
_db.collection('carts').doc(uid).collection('items').add({
    'itemID': item.itemID,
    'price': item.price,
   
  });
```

Comment: After moving everything into the main collection 'carts' and searching for .where('uid', isEqualTo: uid), it's doing the same thing. I think there could be something wrong with the deleting query that is stuck, so when I add more items they are added and instantly deleted!

Answer (score 0):

The original delete query doesn't work. I found it on another post, this one works perfectly.

```
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('carts').where('uid', isEqualTo: uid).get().then((value) => {
        value.docs.forEach((doc) {
          doc.reference.delete();
        })
      });
```